# Button image re-size in High Resolution Screens

Tags: c++, mfc, dpi, image-scaling, image-size

I have a project with a lot of button bars and a lot of graphic interfaces, the problem I have is that with graphic cards and new high-resolution monitors, when scaling, for example, 150% is set in the screen configuration, the buttons appear with the image very small; the image inside is not re-scaled to 150% like the rest of the application.

There is a series of buttons to which I assign the image in this way:

```cpp
CImageList ilTest;
ilTest.Create(IDB_IL_DOC, 32, 0, RGB(255, 0, 255));
m_picDoc.SetIcon (ilTest.ExtractIcon (0));

...
```

Can it be modified in some way so that the button image is scaled in the same proportion as the rest of the interface?

Comment: I'd add *MFC* in the tags

Comment: Then I'd promptly give up. MFC has been obsolete far before there was a DPI setting, it is absolutely not DPI-aware.

Answer (score 0):

See this article: [MFC applications now default to being DPI-aware](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/mfc-applications-now-default-to-being-dpi-aware/).

To quote the introductory paragraph:

> Hello, I’m Pat Brenner, a developer on the Visual C++ Libraries team,
> mainly responsible for MFC.  I wanted to make you aware of a subtle
> but meaningful change that we have made regarding MFC applications in
> Visual Studio 2010: **all MFC applications are now marked as ‘DPI aware’
> by default**.  This means that your application is expected to handle
> various DPI (dots-per-inch) settings, not just the default (96 DPI),
> because Windows will not automatically scale the user interface
> elements of your application to match the selected DPI of the system.

It eventually links to this article: [High DPI Desktop Application Development on Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/hidpi/high-dpi-desktop-application-development-on-windows) which goes into details with some examples.

I admit that I have not delved into addressing the DPI issues in my own projects. It is something I should do.